# How to make generic `class Foo<T=any>` with specific initial values in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have this code, for a generic class:

```
export default class XYZValues<T = any> extends Observable {
    private _x: T = undefined
    private _y: T = undefined
    private _z: T = undefined
}
```

but it says undefined is not assignable to T.

Sub classes should specify types, f.e. `XYZNumberValues` would `extends XYZValues<number>` for T, and `XYZStringValues` would `extends XYZValues<string>`.

At the moment, I'm using `any`, but it doesn't feel right:

```
export default class XYZValues<T = any> extends Observable {
    private _x: T = undefined as any
    private _y: T = undefined as any
    private _z: T = undefined as any
}
```

Is there a recommended way to create generic classes with default values (such as undefined) without using `any`?

Comment: try using `unknown`

Comment: The type error is correct. What if I do extend `XYZValues<number>`? I'm pretty sure `undefined` is not a number.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `_x` etc.?  Subclasses won't have access to `private` properties, so I'm confused.  Anyway you might want to make these properties optional like `private _x?: T` or required-but-possibly-undefined like `private _x: T | undefined`.   Or maybe something else would be more appropriate; could you provide more detail about your use cases?